# install.packages() can't find shared .so object file

Tags: r

Can anyone suggest a path forward?

While trying to install udunit2 (R package), I get the error below indicating that it can't find the shared object file. Is there an environment variable I'm missing?

`/srv/shiny-server/r-packages` is my custom R package installation directory.

I installed udunits2 per https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/udunits-current/doc/udunits/udunits2.html#Obtain

udunits2 works as a command line tool.

UPDATE: libudunits2.so.0 appears to exist on my system:

```
$ la /usr/local/lib
total 568
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root   4096 Apr  4 14:56 ./
drwxr-xr-x. 12 root root   4096 Dec  8  2016 ../
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 199466 Apr  4 14:56 libudunits2.a
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root    889 Apr  4 14:56 libudunits2.la*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     20 Apr  4 10:04 libudunits2.so -> libudunits2.so.0.1.0*
lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root     20 Apr  4 10:04 libudunits2.so.0 -> libudunits2.so.0.1.0*
-rwxr-xr-x.  1 root root 131080 Apr  4 10:04 libudunits2.so.0.1.0*
```

I'm working on a Red Hat Enterprise 6.9 system with DevToolSet-7 installed (so, g++ 7.2.1).

```
> install.packages("udunits2")
Installing package into ‘/srv/shiny-server/r-packages’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'http://cran.us.r-project.org/src/contrib/udunits2_0.13.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 67182 bytes (65 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 65 KB

* installing *source* package ‘udunits2’ ...
** package ‘udunits2’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
checking for gcc... gcc -std=gnu99
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables... 
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether gcc -std=gnu99 accepts -g... yes
checking for gcc -std=gnu99 option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... yes
checking how to run the C preprocessor... gcc -std=gnu99 -E
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for ANSI C header files... yes
checking for sys/types.h... yes
checking for sys/stat.h... yes
checking for stdlib.h... yes
checking for string.h... yes
checking for memory.h... yes
checking for strings.h... yes
checking for inttypes.h... yes
checking for stdint.h... yes
checking for unistd.h... yes
checking udunits2.h usability... yes
checking udunits2.h presence... yes
checking for udunits2.h... yes
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... yes
configure: creating ./config.status
config.status: creating src/Makevars
** libs
gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/local/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG  -I/usr/local/include    -fpic  -I/include  -c udunits2_R.c -o udunits2_R.o
gcc -std=gnu99 -shared -L/lib -o udunits2.so udunits2_R.o -ludunits2 -lexpat -lexpat -ludunits2
installing to /srv/shiny-server/r-packages/udunits2/libs
** R
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/srv/shiny-server/r-packages/udunits2/libs/udunits2.so':
  libudunits2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/srv/shiny-server/r-packages/udunits2’

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpRqD9L6/downloaded_packages’
Warning message:
In install.packages("udunits2") :
  installation of package ‘udunits2’ had non-zero exit status
```

Answer (score 15):

You are misreading the error message. It actually says

```
libudunits2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

and you can fix this by doing the RHEL equivalent of

```
sudo apt-get install libudunits2-dev
```

to get the headers and linkable library needed to *build* besides the `libudunits2` you may already have which only allows you to *run* shared object code, but not link against it.

Apologies for the `apt-get` example by I don't have quick way to search `yum` for you.  *The principle remains the same*: You *need* the matching `-dev` package.

Comment: I don't think I did misread it... although I misspoke in my original post title...

I've updated the post to point out that libudunits2.so.0 does, indeed, already exist -- created and installed when I installed udunits2 from source, I presume...

I've successfully installed the R package (udunits2) by copying the libudunits2.* files to /lib -- but that's obviously not the way I should have done it...

How can one pass an additional library directory to the usual R install.packages()?

Comment: Or rather: How can one have R also look to /usr/local/lib/ for DLLs at package load?

Comment: You seem confused about the role of _system_ shared libraries. You need the (non-R) library [udunits](https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/downloads/udunits/index.jsp) from UCAR. I get this ready-made from Debian / Ubuntu; you may have to look at an rpm or install from source. _This step has nothing to do with the CRAN package._  Once done, you have a new system library and you can try `install.packages("udunits2")` again.

Comment: I’m clearly confused about something, but that’s not it, Dirk. I think my original post clearly shows that (at the system level) I *have* installed both udunits2 and libudunits2-devel. I also clearly show that (in R) install.packages doesn’t work, because it can’t find the already installed libudunits2.so, which lives in /usr/local/lib/ on my RHEL. If I `cp /usr/local/lib/libudunits2* /lib/` then I can successfully install.packages. I could `ln -s` instead... but is there a more direct way to tell R to include  /usr/local/lib/ ? Is it just using the user’s $PATH? Something else?

Comment: I don't know. I have been building packages off CRAN, and for CRAN, for over 20 years.  This one used to be a challenge because of the external library; for me it is no longer a challenge as it _just works_ with the Debian / Ubuntu supplied libudunit2 just like tens of thousands of other packages (as you can easily test in a Debian docker container or other virtual environment).   So your troubles may be RHEL related, or they may due to the fact we talk past each other. Truly sorry but  I cannot help you longer here, good luck going forward.

Comment: I had the same issue. I had it installed in a non-standard path, then tried to install the 
R package with`configure.args='--with-udunits2-lib=/xxx/local/lib --with-udunits2-include=/xxx/local/include'` and also tried to mess with the LD_LIBRARY_PATH, could install, but not load (same error as above). Lastly, I managed with the equivalent of what @DirkEddelbuettel suggested:
`sudo yum install udunits2-devel`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

In the R console, run:

```
Sys.setenv(UDUNITS2_LIBS="/path/to/udunits2/lib")
Sys.setenv(UDUNITS2_INCLUDE="/path/to/udunits2/include")
```

Then

```
install.packages("udunits2")
```

**UPDATE**

This solution does not work for me anymore. Installing libudunits-dev from the ubuntu repos worked.